# JQuery - make element hidden when leaving TWO elements

Tags: jquery, hover, hide

The code below makes the #testnav1 element appear when hovering over #admin1.

I want to be able to hide #testnav1 when the mouseleaves BOTH elements, not just one or the other. Basically, its part of a dropdown menu that makes #testnav1 appear to the left of the #admin1 element when hovered over.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#admin1").hover(function() {
            var x = $(this).offset();
            var leftAjust = x.left - $("#testnav1").css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - 1;
            $("#testnav1").css({"position": "absolute", "left": leftAjust, "top": x.top}).show();                
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $("#admin1").hover(function() {
     var x = $(this).offset();
     var leftAjust = x.left - $("#testnav1").css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - 1;
     $("#testnav1").css({"position": "absolute", "left": leftAjust, "top": x.top}).show();                
 },function(){
     $("#testnav1").hide();// hide the element on mouse leave
 });
```

**Updated**

```
var flagAdmin=false;var flagTestNav=false;
$("#testnav1").mouseleave(function(){
   flagTestNav=true;
   hideTestNav();
})
$("#admin1").hover(function() {
     flagAdmin=false;flagTestNav=false;
     var x = $(this).offset();
     var leftAjust = x.left - $("#testnav1").css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - 1;
     $("#testnav1").css({"position": "absolute", "left": leftAjust, "top": x.top}).show();                
},function(){
     flagAdmin=true;
     hideTestNav();
});
function hideTestNav(){
    if(flagAdmin==true && flagTestNav==true)
    {
        $("#testnav1").hide();// hides only if both admin and testnav mouse-leaves
    }
}
```

Comment: Its disappearing correctly, but I would like the #testnav1 element to remain visible whilst hovered over. So basically, #testnav1 needs to be visible as long as #admin1 or #testnav1 are hovered over. Otherwise, it needs to be hidden.

Comment: The #testnav1 element does not disappear when leaving the #admin element, only when leaving itself (testnav1)